# Clojure to remove non-numbers from a string

Tags: clojure

I have the following code to try to remove non-numbers froma  string:

```
(apply str 
    (flatten 
        (map 
            (fn[x] 
                (if (number? x) x)) 
                "ij443kj"
        )
    )
)
```

But it always returns an empty string instead of "443". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here and how I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

number? doesn't work that way. It checks the type. If you pass it a character, you'll get back false every time, no matter what the character is.

I'd probably use a regular expression for this, but if you want to keep the same idea of the program, you could do something like

```
(apply str (filter #(#{\0,\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9} %) "abc123def"))
```

or even better

```
(apply str (filter #(Character/isDigit %) myString))
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I agree that number? doesn't work that way. Which function should I use instead?

Comment: Note that you dont need to wrap you set in a function. Set implments IFn so you can just write (filter #{\1\2\3} "abc123def")

Comment: Great that worked for me too: I just had an issue with Doubles, so I have changed it like this: (filter #(#{\0,\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9,\.} %) my-double-number)  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is an even simpler way, use a regular expression:

```
(.replaceAll "ij443kj" "[^0-9]" "")
```

Answer (score 1):

get the char's int values...

```
(map int (apply vector "0123456789"))
```

-> (48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57)

then fix it:

```
(defn my-int
[char]
(- (int char) 48))
```

now let's try this again, shall we?

```
(map my-int (apply vector "0123456789"))
```

-> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

and just to get a warm-and-fuzzy that they're integers...

```
(map #(* % 10) (map my-int (apply vector "0123456789")))
```

-> (0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90)

```
(reduce + (map my-int (apply vector "0123456789")))
```

-> 45

Answer (score 1):

in case you will handling decimal

```
#(re-seq #"[0-9\.]+" "ij443kj")
```